# Append to XML file

Tags: java, xml, append, document

I am writing a Java application with a method to save data to XML.

Here is my code:

```
private void SaveToXML(String strCity, String strDate, String strforecast, String strminDegrees, String FileName)
{
    try 
    {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Weather");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    Element weatherElement = doc.createElement(strCity);
    rootElement.appendChild(weatherElement);

    Element dateElement = doc.createElement("Date");
    weatherElement.appendChild(dateElement);

    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue(strDate);
    dateElement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    Element forecast = doc.createElement("forecast");
    forecast.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strforecast));
    dateElement.appendChild(forecast);

    Element mindegrees = doc.createElement("mindegrees");
    mindegrees.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strminDegrees));
    dateElement.appendChild(mindegrees);

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(FileName));

    transformer.transform(source, result);

   } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
    tfe.printStackTrace();
  }    
}
```

Method call:

```
SaveToXML("Auckland", "24-05-2013", "Fine", "10", "Test.xml");
```

Here is the output XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Weather>
    <Auckland>
        <Date id="24-05-2013">
            <forecast>Fine</forecast>
            <mindegrees>10</mindegrees>
        </Date>
    </Auckland>
</Weather>
```

Can I please have some help to modify the code so that data is appended to the document in the correct element when the method is called.

E.g, If the method is called a second time with the City of Auckland, the weather details will be placed in the Auckland element. If a City is passed as a parameter that is not already in the document, a new element for that City will be created.

**UPDATE2**

This is my current code that performs an error:

```
private void SaveToXML(String strCity, String strDate, String strforecast, String strminDegrees, String FileName)
{
    try 
    {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    //Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File(FileName));
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Weather");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    NodeList weatherNodes = rootElement.getElementsByTagName(strCity);// do we already have node?
    Element weatherElement;
      if(weatherNodes.getLength() > 0){                     // if so reuse
        weatherElement = (Element) weatherNodes.item(0);
        System.out.println("Found");
    }else {                                               // else create
        weatherElement = doc.createElement(strCity);
        rootElement.appendChild(weatherElement);    
    }

    Element dateElement = doc.createElement("Date");
    weatherElement.appendChild(dateElement);

    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue(strDate);
    dateElement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    Element forecast = doc.createElement("forecast");
    forecast.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strforecast));
    dateElement.appendChild(forecast);

    Element mindegrees = doc.createElement("mindegrees");
    mindegrees.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strminDegrees));
    dateElement.appendChild(mindegrees);

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(FileName));

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code generates this error at runtime:

> [Fatal Error] Test.xml:1:177: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

**UPDATE3**

Here is the code that is working:

```
private void SaveToXML(String strCity, String strDate, String strforecast, String strminDegrees, String FileName)
{
    try 
    {

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc;
    File file = new File(FileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        doc.appendChild(doc.createElement("Weather"));
    } else {
        doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(FileName));
    }

    Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
    Element weatherElement;
    NodeList weatherNodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName(strCity);
    if (weatherNodes.getLength() > 0) {
        weatherElement = (Element) weatherNodes.item(0);
    } else {
        weatherElement = doc.createElement(strCity);
        rootElement.appendChild(weatherElement); 
    }

    Element dateElement = doc.createElement("Date");
    weatherElement.appendChild(dateElement);

    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue(strDate);
    dateElement.setAttributeNode(attr);

    Element forecast = doc.createElement("forecast");
    forecast.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strforecast));
    dateElement.appendChild(forecast);

    Element mindegrees = doc.createElement("mindegrees");
    mindegrees.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strminDegrees));
    dateElement.appendChild(mindegrees);

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(FileName));

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify how you update the document structure for DOM,

modify

```
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Weather");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

Element weatherElement = doc.createElement(strCity);
rootElement.appendChild(weatherElement);
```

to

```
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Weather");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

  NodeList weatherNodes = rootElement.getElementsByTagName(strCity);// do we already have node?
  Element weatherElement;
  if(weatherNodes.getLength() > 0){                     // if so reuse
    weatherElement = (Element) weatherNodes.item(0);
}else {                                               // else create
    weatherElement = doc.createElement(strCity);
    rootElement.appendChild(weatherElement);    
}
```

Be aware the DOM is really intended for small documents if this is going to get very large
you will need to look at something like STaX.

Comment: I am getting an error with the method call: getElementsByTagName - cannot find symbol.

Comment: At the moment, old entries are being overwritten. I would like to append each entry to the XML file.

Comment: safest way is to load file. make modification, then write file.

Answer (score 0):

If XML file already exists you should parse it and update the city if it already exists or add otherwise. Then rewrite XML.

```
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc;
    File file = new File(FileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        doc.appendChild(doc.createElement("Weather"));
    } else {
        doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
    }

    Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
    Element weatherElement = createWeatherElement(strCity, strDate, strforecast, strminDegrees, doc);
    NodeList weatherNodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName(strCity);
    if (weatherNodes.getLength() > 0) {
        rootElement.replaceChild(weatherElement, weatherNodes.item(0));
    } else {
        rootElement.appendChild(weatherElement);
    }

    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    ...

private Element createWeatherElement(String strCity, String strDate, String strforecast, String strminDegrees, Document doc) {
    Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
    Element weatherElement = doc.createElement(strCity);
              ...
    return weatherElement;
}
```

Comment: The first line of your above code generates this error: unreported exception org.xml.sax.SAXException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: Just declare it in your method's throws clause

Comment: There are some problems, see my update, just extract your code that creates a whetherElement into a createWhetherElement func

Comment: Can you please explain what it means yo create a weather element?

Comment: See update, it's just a piece of your code in a separate function